# Transfer AWS promotional credits

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

About a year ago, my startup received some promotional credits. At the time, the company didn't have any credit card or e-mail so I redeemed the credits to my own AWS account. We now consider that it's more appropriate for the company to have its dedicated AWS account. I would therefore like to transfer those *promotional* credits to the new company account.

It seems that this is not possible, but surely there must be some way around this? What are my options?

Comment: I have tried to move AWS credits between my own accounts without success. This was a while ago, maybe this has changed but I doubt it. You will need to open a billing support request in the AWS console.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming.

Comment: You should ask AWS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Introductory Consideration

1st of all we must keep in mind the [AWS Promotional Credit Terms & Conditions](https://aws.amazon.com/awscredits/)

> 3. **You may not sell, license, rent, or otherwise transfer Promotional Credit.** Promotional Credit may be applied only to your own AWS
>    account. Promotional Credit has no intrinsic value, is not redeemable
>    for cash, has no cash value, is nonrefundable, and serves merely as a
>    means to provide an incentive to use our Services. Promotional Credit
>    may not be purchased for cash, and we and our affiliates do not sell
>    Promotional Credit.

However, you have **2 ways to share / move these credits** with other AWS accounts you own as presented below

---

#### Option 1: Transferring credits ownership via AWS Support Case

You will need to open a [billing support request in the AWS console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-get-answers.html) and request your AWS promotional credits to be transfer to a new account that is also under your ownership.

Thereof, how do I transfer ownership of AWS Credits?

1. Open the AWS Support Center.
2. Choose *"Create case"*.
3. Enter the details of your case: Choose *"Account and billing support"*. For Type, choose *"Account"*. For Category, choose *"Ownership Transfer"*. And detail clearly which will be the destination account to which you want to transfer the credits ownership from your current account.
4. Choose a contact method.
5. Choose *"Submit"*.
6. Follow up on the case with the AWS support team to transfer the credits.

---

#### Option 2: Share credits by joining or creating an AWS organization with the AWS account that has active credits on it

You should choose between the below presented options depending which one best suit your scenario:

1. **Joining an existing AWS Organization:** AWS applies credits under an account to the AWS organization's consolidated bill, beginning the first full billing cycle after an account joins the organization. **NOTE** ["Sharing Credits" must be turned on](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/useconsolidatedbilling-credits.html#credit-sharing).

   - **RESULT:** So your Account credits will be shared with the Management and Members accounts of the AWS Organization you've joined.
2. **Create an AWS Organization:** Since AWS applies credits under an account to the AWS organization's consolidated bill, all the Organizations members accounts credits will be shared across all applicable usage incurred by member accounts. **NOTE** ["Sharing Credits" must be turned on](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/useconsolidatedbilling-credits.html#credit-sharing).

   - **RESULT:** After creating the Organization with your account, this will now be your new Management account. You can now invite pre-existing accounts or create new organization member accounts that will be able to use your Management account credits.

Read More: [How are credits and promotions calculated in an organization in AWS Organizations?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/consolidated-billing-credits/)

Comment: May 2022 - I've tried the first method. Unfortunately, they have replied saying that, for security reasons, they don't perform that kind of operation.

Comment: @DaviDoro, What is the best way to transfer aws Credits from one account to another account?

Comment: @SunilGajula The second method does work. I've tried earlier this year (2022).